# "Pure" Prototype Language

Tags: self, prototype-programming

I'm looking for a "pure" prototype language that I can study.  I'm using the definition of "pure" meaning (quoted from Wikipedia):

> Under pure prototyping, which is also referred to as concatenative
>   prototypes, and is exemplified in the Kevo language, there are no
>   visible pointers or links to the original prototype from which an
>   object is cloned. The prototype object is copied exactly, but given a
>   different name (or reference). Behavior and attributes are simply
>   duplicated as-is.

Kevo no longer appears to be supported, and I am unable to find any significant amount of documentation.  It may be that there are no "pure" prototype languages in use today.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would [this link](http://www.scribd.com/doc/52173566/66/Kevo) help you?

Found [another link](http://lively.cs.tut.fi/publications/TR6-JavaScriptConcatenation-Taivalsaari.pdf) for you, from the creator of kevo, Antero Taivalsaari. At first glance it looks like the prototype nature of kevo is excaggerated to say the least.

Comment: Looks like an interesting read.  There's is not much information on Kevo, but better than nothing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Granted that "pure" is a rather abstract quality.  But in my research Self is a rather good candidate and it has Ok support.  If you are willing to forego multiple parent links (prototypes) then JavaScript is actually reasonably good.

In my work, I've used Self to understand and explore the various aspects of prototypical language and its environment.  Then I re-implement what I really need to complete programs for deployment in JavaScript.  That in turn allows me to run either in a browser or using NodeJS.

Comment: "Under pure prototyping, which is also referred to as concatenative prototypes, and is exemplified in the Kevo language, there are no visible pointers or links to the original prototype from which an object is cloned. The prototype object is copied exactly, but given a different name (or reference). Behavior and attributes are simply duplicated as-is."  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming#Concatenation)